# TimeSpan subtract method return negative TImeSpan

Tags: vb.net, timespan

These two TimeSpan are stored in the Database with 24hr format. No date, only TimeSpan.

```
Dim r As TimeSpan
Dim tsStart As TimeSpan
Dim tsEnd As TimeSpan

'tsStard is 12:27:30 (pm) this happened first
'tsEnd is 00:10:25 (am) then this happened later

'You can't store 24:10:25 in the column type Time(7)

r = tsEnd.Subtract(tsStart)
```

'the r = -12:17:05

Is there any TimeSpan method to get this right? Thank you.

Comment: Without the date and assuming that tsStart and tsEnd can refer to times on different days, there is no method to get it "right". You have no way of knowing how many days are correctly in the span. At this point you're generating values as opposed to calculating them.

Comment: I'm writing a simple app to calculate check-in and check-out time of the students. It keeps record of time-in and time-out of a particular date. There's another column that stores only Date type. . So, in the record you have Date, TimeIn, TimeOut. Yes, it'll be more easier if column TimeIn and TimeOut are type of DateTime. But, I'm experimenting with data type Time(7).

Comment: Time(7) takes 5 bytes, and smalldatetime takes 4 bytes. If you don't need accuracy below a minute, smalldatetime consumes less storage and will save you from problems with long timespans. Personally, I would still tend to use a full DateTime for start and end because it's more robust in the long term, and 6 to 8 more bytes per record is not a huge increase in storage consumption.

Comment: Gotta agree with jball here - DateTime is the way to go. If you use that, you won't need to perform tricks every time you want to make a calculation, and you won't have to embed certain assumptions in your code (like 'this process always takes less than 24 hours').

Comment: Hmm. I just modified the table column. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know that `tsEnd` always represents a later point in time than `tsStart` but your database doesn't store the dates, you can solve this by adding 24 hours to the end when the end is less than the start (pardon the C# syntax):

```
if (tsEnd < tsStart) {
    r = tsEnd.Add(new TimeSpan(24, 0, 0)).Subtract(tsStart);
} else {
    r = tsEnd.Subtract(tsStart);
}
```

As jball noted in the comments, this assumes that `tsEnd` is never later by more than one day, though we have no way to determine otherwise.

Comment: That assumes that tsEnd is never later by more than 1 day.

Comment: True, but there's no way to tell otherwise, given the constraints presented here.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the Duration() method on TimeSpan, it will guarantee that your result is positive, no matter what order you do the subtraction in.

For example:

```
Dim r As TimeSpan
Dim tsStart As TimeSpan
Dim tsEnd As TimeSpan

'tsStart is 12:27:30 
'tsEnd is 00:10:25 

r = tsEnd.Subtract(tsStart).Duration()
'r = 12:17:05
```

Comment: This gives the wrong value, however. The correct value of r is 11:42:55, not 12:17:05.

Comment: `Duration` is IMO a fairly odd name for an absolute value method, so it doesn't surprise me that it could catch someone out.

Answer (score 0):

tsEnd is less than tsStart, so `r = tsEnd.Subtract(tsStart)` should result in a negative number. Perhaps you want to subtract tsEnd from tsStart `r = tsStart.Subtract(tsEnd)`, or your variables are being set to the reverse of what they should be?

Depending on your situation you may want to call `r = r.Duration()`, which returns the absolute value of `r`.

If you are worried about wrapping days, you'll need the date - there's no way to know how many days have gone by just from the time component.

Comment: I'm trying to calculate the how much time has spent. You see tsStart happened first at 12:27:30 (pm) , tsEnd happened later at 00:10:25(am) which is 12 hr different.